# Bound states in two and three dimensional delta potential in non relativistic QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, renormalization, boundary-conditions

I would like to find bound state energies in let's say 2D delta function potential. So my eigenvalue equation is:

$$(-\frac{1}{2}\Delta - g\delta(r)) \psi = -B \psi$$

and by the means of Fourier transform : $$\frac{p^2}{2} \phi(\textbf{p}) - g \Psi(\textbf{0})  = -B \phi(\textbf{p})$$

$$\phi(p) := \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} d^n \textbf{r} \exp(i \textbf{p} \cdot \textbf{r}) \Psi(\textbf{r})$$

So there's my problem. I know that I have to put a cutoff $\Lambda$ on momenta since I have infinite integrals and stuff. One of my problems is that if I would go back to position representation then I would have to change all the integrals, fourier transforms and the laplacian would be different too. So that's probably not the best way to approach this.

How can I find this energies?

Comment: This gets into renormalization of singular potentials, addressed by Sarang Gopalakrishnan in [Self-Adjointness and the
Renormalization of Singular Potentials](http://www.amherst.edu/media/view/10264/original/gopalakrishnan06.pdf).